# What is a fanfare and on which instrument would it be best to play it on?

Tags: composition, brass, woodwinds

I want to compose a song for a woodwind or a brass instrument. I am not too experienced at composing and am wondering what a fanfare is and what are some good and/or famous examples of them. Also, which instrument(trumpet?) would be best to compose and play with. Any key is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fanfare is a particular style of music, that's often used to introduce something important, or get people's attention. They are not a subtle piece of music. They're usually pretty short and sweet, as well.

The most idiomatic instrument for a fanfare would be a trumpet, or its older cousin, the bugle. Writing for bugle is a little bit more complicated, because it can only play a [limited set of notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugle). The trumpet has valves, which allows it to play a much wider range of notes.

There are many examples of fanfares which you could look at for inspiration, but I'd suggest just using Google and/or YouTube. If it's an older piece of music, you should look on [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/) for sheet music. Here's a link to the [fanfares category](http://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Fanfares).